# How to remove delimiters from a given RegEx?

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-group

my input:

```
str = "User-123"
```

o/p:

```
name: User 
id: 123
```

another input:

```
str = "User 123"// current this works with my regex.
```

o/p: As above

other possible inputs:

```
str = "User:123"
str = "User/123"
str = "User:123"
```

code:

```
let m = value.match(/([a-z]+\s*\d+)\s+([a-z]+\s*\d+|\d+\s*[a-z]+)/i);
if (m) {return true}
else {return false}
```

if I have delimiters the above code return false as it does not find the match for the delimiters. I want to return true for all the scenarios listed above.

currently it removes only the whitespaces, how can I remove delimiters from this regex as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "delimiters"? Is this a list of characters?

Comment: The first and third *"possible inputs"* are the same. Are you wanting to split any username (A-Z) and ID (0-9) no matter if the input includes a space, `-` or  `:`?

Comment: a delimiter can be anything in my case (: , ., /, ?, =, +, -, _,) basically an non-alphanumeric chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to split on a non-alphanumeric character:

```js
let inputs  = [
  "User:123",
  "User/123",
  "User:123",
  "User-123",
  "User 123"
]

for (i of inputs){
    let [name, id] = i.split(/[^a-z0-9]/i)
    console.log("name:", name, "id:", id)
}
```

Comment: thanks @mark for the answer, I'm not sure if I can create an array of input strings , the delimiters could be anything  (: ,  ., /, ?, =, +,)and they cannot be predefined. I dont think creating an array of inputs will solve this issue..

Comment: @user1234 I created an array of inputs to make it easy to demonstrate the regex on all your potential inputs in a loop rather than one at a time. `let [name, id] = i.split(/[^a-z0-9]/i)` works with one input named `i` and gives you a `name` and `id` from the input.

Answer (score 1):

You might consider simplifying your expression. Using capturing groups, you can simply add/remove any delimiters that you wish. For instance, [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/5xMjMQ/1) shows how you might use capturing group:

```
([A-z]+)(:|\/)([0-9]+)
```

[image]

#### Graph

This graph shows how the expression work:

[image]

#### Code

This code shows how to do so and does a basic benchmark with 1 million times repeat.

```js
repeat = 1000000;

start = Date.now();


for (var i = repeat; i >= 0; i--) {
 var string = 'User/123';
 var regex = /([A-z]+)(:|\/)([0-9]+)/g;

 var match = string.replace(regex, "$1$3");
}

end = Date.now() - start;

console.log(match + " is a match  ");
console.log(end / 1000 + " is the runtime of " + repeat + " times benchmark test.  ");
```